# JSF selectboolean checkbox in datatable not showing up

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

Firstly I would provide my configuration details:
JSF - 1.2
Icefaces - 1.8
Servlet - 2.5

I am trying to put an `ice:selectBooleanCheckbox` in a datatable. But, I am facing an expception repeatedly:

> icelogin.jspx @54,59 value="#{o.checkBox}": ELResolver cannot handle a
>   null base Object with identifier 'o'

Here is my jspx code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
   xmlns:ft="http://facestrace.sourceforge.net">
   <f:view>
      <head>
         <title>JSF Jump start</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <ice:form>
            <h3>User Name and Password</h3>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <ice:outputLabel value="Name"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <ice:inputText value="#{userLogin.name}"/>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <ice:outputLabel value="Password"/>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <ice:inputText value="#{userLogin.password}"/>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
            <ice:dataTable value="#{userLogin.orderList}" var="o">
               <ice:column>
                  <!-- column header -->
                  <f:facet name="header">Order No</f:facet>
                  <!-- row record -->
                  #{o.orderNo}
               </ice:column>
               <ice:column>
                  <f:facet name="header">Product Name</f:facet>
                  #{o.productName}
               </ice:column>
               <ice:column>
                  <f:facet name="header">Price</f:facet>
                  #{o.price}
               </ice:column>
               <ice:column>
                  <!-- column header -->
                  <f:facet name="header">Checkbox</f:facet>
                  <!-- row record -->
                  <ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{o.checkBox}"/>
                  <!-- #{o.checkBox} --> 
               </ice:column>
               <ice:column>
                  <f:facet name="header">Quantity</f:facet>
                  #{o.qty}
               </ice:column>
            </ice:dataTable>
            <ice:commandButton type="submit"  value="Sign In" action="#userLogin.saveData}"/>
         </ice:form>
      </body>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

If I remove checkBox value from #{o.checkBox} to true or false, it works. I presume that for true, the checkBox should be selected in UI, and false it must remain unselected. But, even if I put code like this

```
<ice:selectBooleanCheckbox value="true"/>
```

check button is being displayed in UI but is not showing up selected though the value is true. I am following this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/), in my case I have one more extra parameter in my bean.

```
boolean checkBox;
```

I have getters and setters in place, and passed to the constructor, all set. What could be wrong?